# Is there a 3D version of nlfilter in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, 3d

I would like to generate 3D (white) objects in black-white images using Matlab's nlfilter (or a similar function/tool).

In 2D, I start with some white seed points, which eventually define the regions/objects in my 2D image. By applying nlfilter successively, I can naturally grow these regions until all pixels are labeled. I'd like to do a similar thing in 3D, but nlfilter works only on 2D images. Treating a 3D image as a stack of 2D images and applying nlfilter on each such slice is one of the possible ways to overcome this problem, but it's not suboptimal. Instead, an nlfilter3d() function would have been much more convenient. 
Does any similar function exist in Matlab or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a 3D equivalent of `nlfilter`, but have you tried solving this out with morphological operations?

Since you are using binary images, I think that morphology can help you out.
For example, for the following 2D image,

[image: seed]

`temp=imdilate(temp0,strel('disk',3));`

will give the following image on output:

[image: dilate]

If you have a 3D binary matrix, defined with, i.e.

`temp0=false(11,11,11);
temp0(5,5,5)=true;`

which is equivalent to the 2D matrix (it has only one white dot and all the rest are black in all three dimensions), then a 3D morphology with the following strel:

`str=true(3,3,3);`

will give on output these 11 images (for every Z plane):

[image: 3Ddilate]

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well, not really. Using `nlfilter` on 2D slices still give a better result in general. It's just a bit more work to get the shapes right.

Comment: Well, good luck then with searching for a solution. I can't help you any further.

All I can say is that the "strel" you use in morphology can be of any type you like and the dilation is based on that "strel". If you knew that/tried that and that still doesn't help, then I wish you good luck again :)

Cheers!